# why prefetch_related not working in django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-orm

I have these models

```
class Product(models.Model):
    product_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null = False, unique=True)
    product_title = models.CharField(max_length=255, null = True)
    product_price = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    brand = models.ForeignKey(Brand, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    product_type = models.ForeignKey(Product_type, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)

class Product_feature(models.Model):
    product_feature_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    feature = models.ForeignKey(Feature, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, related_name='product_features')
    product_feature_value = models.CharField(max_length=255, null = False)
```

So I want to fetch product_features for each product and i used prefetch_related like this:

```
product_data = Product.objects.filter(brand__brand_id = brand_data.brand_id).prefetch_related('product_features')
```

but in template it's now showing related model data here's template code:

```
{% for products in product_data %}
      {{ products.product_name }}
      {% for a in product_data.product_features.all %}
         <li>{{ a.product_feature_value }}</li>
      {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Please help me I tried everything but nothing works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You specify `product_data.product_features`, but `product_data` is a *collection* of `Product`s. It should be `product.product_features` (since `products` is a single `Product` object, you better name this `product`, not <s>`products`</s>):

```
{% for product in product_data %}
      {{ product.product_name }}
      {% for a in product.product_features.all %}
         <li>{{ a.product_feature_value }}</li>
      {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```